# Pulling multiple levels of data efficiently in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to build a print process, which consists of printing a batch of financial applications using Rails.

I am printing around 100 applications, which consist of multiple levels of data (the application itself, sub-models, and their sub-models).

At the moment the page is very inefficient as it is doing a lot of N+1 querying which is causing the performance to be poor.

Question is, is there an efficient way of getting this data out of the database.  I've tried pulling the forms with `includes()` for all the sub-models, but this doesn't help with the models that are below that (for instance, `income_line_items` on a `financial_history` model)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using a nested hash to access the sub-sub-models? Something like:

```
@app = Application.includes(:first_submodel, 
                            {:second_submodel => [:first_sub_submodel, :second_sub_submodel]},
                            {:third_submodel  => :third_sub_submodel})
```