# How do I access the joined columns when using custom Arel joins?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have a simple database with the following schema:

- `Book` has many `Tags` through `Taggings`
- `Book` has many `Users` through `ReadingStatuses`

What I want to do is to list all of the books, their tags, and a reading status of the currently logged in user with each book. I've managed to write this using Arel (with the `arel-helpers` gem), but I don't know how to access the results in each `book` entry while iterating over the `books` array.

Here's the query

```
join_params = Book.arel_table.join(ReadingStatus.arel_table, Arel::OuterJoin)
                             .on(Book[:id].eq(ReadingStatus[:book_id])
                             .and(ReadingStatus[:user_id].eq(User.first.id)))
                             .join_sources
books = Book.all.includes(:tags).joins(join_params)
```

and the respective SQL it generates

```
SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "reading_statuses"
ON "books"."id" = "reading_statuses"."book_id"
AND "reading_statuses"."user_id" = 'XXX'
```

There's nothing really to be done with the `tags`, since `includes` will automatically make everything work when calling `book.tags`, but what I don't know is **how to access the `ReadingStatus` that is joined to each `Book` when iterating over the `books` result?**

Comment: by adding your own select as in  Book.select("books.*, reading_statuses.*").includes(:tags).joins(join_params)

Comment: @ilanberci How do I access it then? `book.reading_status` doesn't work even with the select

Comment: The fields get combined into the final result set.  (Although you think you are getting a Book class in your result set, you aren't.)  Just call books.user_id and you will see

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [includes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) instead of joins. "includes" does eager fetching, but if you don't mind that it might make you query look a lot simpler.

You will also not have to explicitly mention the left outer join.

See if that helps:

[Pulling multiple levels of data efficiently in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829164/pulling-multiple-levels-of-data-efficiently-in-rails)

[Rails: How to fetch records that are 2 'has_many' levels deep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041605/rails-how-to-fetch-records-that-are-2-has-many-levels-deep)

[Eager loading](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations)

Make sure you include the call to [references](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references)

"ReadingStatus[:user_id].eq(User.first.id)" can be shifted into the where clause

Comment: includes won't work in this case, since I need to customize how things are being joined, instead of just loading the associated records.

Comment: What do you mean customize joins? Includes joins on the same relationships that you are joining. ie. the foreign keys book_id. "ReadingStatus[:user_id].eq(User.first.id)" can be shifted into the where clause right?
Are you using includes with the call to references?